# Javascript error in rails app (locally run)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xss

I am trying to move a development environment from production to my local machine (Ubuntu), and when I get the code up and running on my box, the site works in rails but I get this JS error:

Permission denied for http://ad.doubleclick.net to call method Location.toString on http://localhost:3000.

Line 0

Do you have any idea how to fix JS problems, or should I disable the ads in development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an error that you can ignore. Its probably contained to an iframe created by the advertisement module.

I'm pretty sure that error occurs on the production version too, unless the production version is actually hosted at `ad.doubleclick.net`, which I guess its not :)